# How do I get a call stack of another thread?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, profiling, callstack

Is it possible to get a `Kernel#caller` output of one thread from another one? Or even better the stack of the main thread from the background one, which would work for me as a kind of profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is Thread#backtrace method to get function backtrace for some thread:

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Thread.html#method-i-backtrace

> `backtrace` → array click to toggle source
>
> Returns the current backtrace of the target thread.

For usage example check this project: https://github.com/frsyuki/sigdump (it will show backtraces and some memory usage info for ruby and jruby)

> `sigdump` - In short: SIGQUIT of Java VM for Ruby (Use signal to show stacktrace of a Ruby process without restarting it).
>
> ... Just sending SIGCONT signal will dump backtrace and memory profile to /tmp/sigdump-.log file.
>
> sigdump dumps following information (see also Sample output):
>
> Backtrace of all threads

https://github.com/frsyuki/sigdump/blob/master/lib/sigdump.rb

```
    dump_all_thread_backtrace(io)
...
    Thread.list.each do |thread|
      dump_backtrace(thread, io)
...
  def self.dump_backtrace(thread, io)
    status = thread.status
    if status == nil
      status = "finished"
    elsif status == false
      status = "error"
    end

    io.write "  Thread #{thread} status=#{status} priority=#{thread.priority}\n"
    if thread.backtrace
      thread.backtrace.each {|bt|
        io.write "      #{bt}\n"
      }
    end

    io.flush
    nil
  end
```

Comment: Or check this: http://itreallymatters.net/post/29549982905/generating-thread-dumps-for-ruby-scripts (and about thread#backtrace: "*This method exists in 1.9.  For older Ruby versions there is a different solution, which is not as great because it works only for the current thread.*")